# Active U.S Patent Expired (U.S. Patent No. 8,475,818)

Tags: patentability, patent-applications, patent-lifetime, patent-services

Has Active U.S Patent Expired (U.S. Patent No. 8,475,818) ?
When was issued and when does it expire?

Answer (score 0):

I see that it is due to expire in 2029.

It is easy to look up, probably the easiest to use for something simple is google patents. The [link](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8475818B2/en) to this patent.